# SQL Server - How would I rank products from the last month?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, window-functions, rank

I've already started to flesh things out a bit, but I'm having trouble adding in some sort of window function to get the intended result of having the data, products, called in my code ranked by sales in the last month. If any help could be given, I would greatly appreciate it!

Here is what is being asked:

> The CEO would like to know the sales based on last month's sales. 
>   Please provide her with a query to rank the products by the number of
>   orders in the last month.  There should be NO SKIPPED NUMBERS.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
    P.NAME AS 'Product Name',
    Isnull(Count(DISTINCT O.OrderID), 0) AS 'Orders Count',
    Sum(Isnull(o.ordertotal, 0)) AS 'Orders Total',
    Sum (Isnull(oi.orderitemquantity, 0)) AS 'Item Total'
 FROM 
    Product P
 INNER JOIN 
    OrderItem OI ON OI.ProductID = P.ProductID
 INNER JOIN 
    Orders O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
GROUP BY 
    P.Name
```

This does need to be in a stored procedure as well, so any help with that would be great too.

Comment: SQL Server has a function for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql

Comment: Alright pal - as @Caramiriel says, there are functions available to RANK data for you based on the criteria you give it. What are the problems or questions you have around creating it as a stored proc?

Comment: Please provide sample data and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `CTE` and a `RANK()` function

```
create procedure yourProcedure (@TheDate datetime = null)
as

if @TheDate is null 
begin
   set @TheDate = getdate()
end

;with cte as(
SELECT 
    P.NAME AS 'Product Name',
    Isnull(Count(DISTINCT O.OrderID), 0) AS 'Orders Count',
    Sum(Isnull(o.ordertotal, 0)) AS 'Orders Total',
    Sum (Isnull(oi.orderitemquantity, 0)) AS 'Item Total'
 FROM 
    Product P
 INNER JOIN 
    OrderItem OI ON OI.ProductID = P.ProductID
 INNER JOIN 
    Orders O ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
WHERE
    --here is the limiting to the previous month based off the month passed in
    SomeDateField >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @TheDate)-1, 0)
    and
    SomeDateField < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @TheDate), 0)
GROUP BY 
    P.Name)

select
    *
    ,DENSE_RANK() over (order by [Orders Count]) as RK
from cte
```

`DENSE_RANK()` doesn't skip numbers, where as `RANK()` could depending on your dataset.

**Example**

```
declare @table table (ID int identity (1,1), item int)
insert into @table
values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(3),
(3),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6)

select 
    * 
    ,rank() over (order by item) TheRank
    ,dense_rank() over (order by item) TheDenseRank
from @table

+----+------+---------+--------------+
| ID | item | TheRank | TheDenseRank |
+----+------+---------+--------------+
|  1 |    1 |       1 |            1 |
|  2 |    2 |       2 |            2 |
|  3 |    3 |       3 |            3 |
|  4 |    3 |       3 |            3 |
|  5 |    3 |       3 |            3 |
|  6 |    3 |       3 |            3 |
|  7 |    4 |       7 |            4 | --notice difference starting here
|  8 |    5 |       8 |            5 |
|  9 |    6 |       9 |            6 |
+----+------+---------+--------------+
```

Also, this sounds like homework--and if it is, I'd suggest putting that in the question to prevent assumptions.